# UITableView releasing unnaccurately its content

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

i have a `UITableView` within a `UIViewController` that shows a set of data. The funny thing happening here is that everytime `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` calls `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` it returns nil so the table's content is being reset all the time. Other table views in my app work just fine, i must be missing something here.

Does anyone have any clue why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance

PS: I use the recommended init method for the cell:
`- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`

Comment: for whatever info you have given no one can find out the problem..Give us more info or some code snippets..

Comment: There isn't much more i can show really, I am doing everything the standard way so i don't understand what might be causing the problem. I looking for directions that can guide me. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing the same cell reuse identifier to dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier: as you are when you construct the cell?